# Convergence in a sequence space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

For any $n\in \mathbb{N}$ consider the following sequence: 
$$a_n=\left(\underbrace{\frac{1}{n}, \ldots, \frac{1}{n}}_{n \text{ elements}}, 0, 0, 0, 0, \ldots \right).$$

Is there a way to introduce a norm on a sequence space in which $a_n$ will converge to the zero sequence?

Comment: What norms on sequence spaces are you familiar with?

Comment: @Daniel Fischer, $\|\cdot \|_p$ norms

Comment: And when you compute $\lVert a_n\rVert_p$, what's the result?

Comment: Many $\|\cdot\|_p$ will do: $(n\cdot n^{-p})^{1/p}=n^{1/p-1}\to 0$ for $p>1$ (this also applies to $p=\infty$)

Comment: What norms doesn't it converge under? Only one I can find where it doesn't converge is the $\|\dot\|_1$.

Comment: These sequences are linearly independent, so you can just take the "sequence space" to be their span, and choose any linear isomorphism that sends them to a sequence of linearly independent vectors converging to zero in a normed space of your choice.  If you want to rule out a silly norm like this, you should be more precise about what you're looking for.

Comment: That's true, $p>1$ works. Turned out to be an embarassingly easy question.

Comment: The sup norm is such a norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, for instance you can consider ($l_{\infty}, ||\cdot ||_{\infty}$), which is the space of bounded sequences with the supremum norm.